# PHPUnit not showing errors

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm starting to use this testing framework and I have the following problem.

I created a file /tests/CalculatorTest.php. Its the code inside this file:

```
<?php
class CalculatorTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testInstance()
    {
        new Calculator;
    }   
}
?>
```

I know that I haven't any assert inside the first test but what I'm expecting to see is something like "Class 'Calculator' not found" and it only outputs the following:

```
Alan:writingTests alan$ vendor/bin/phpunit tests/
PHPUnit 4.2.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

As you can see, there isn't any error.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the error, I had to change my php.ini configuration display errors.